# How to use ruby-aws-skd#url_for with custom domain s3 bucket?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a working bucket with a subdomain assigned on s3, and I want to create a signed url for a resource using the url_for method of an object with the expire option.

On a initializer, I have:

```
AWS.config({
  :access_key_id => Rails.application.secrets.aws_access_key_id,
  :secret_access_key => Rails.application.secrets.aws_secret_access_key,
  :s3_endpoint => "assets.mydomain.com"
})
```

When I run

```
AWS::S3.new.buckets["assets.mydomain.com"].objects["image.jpg"].url_for(:get, { :expires => 20.hours.from_now }).to_s
```

I get

```
"https://assets.mydomain.com/assets.mydomain.com/image.jpg?WSAccessKeyId=xxx&Expires=xxx&Signature=xxx"
```

Note the bucket url twice.

What do I have to do so this works properly?

PS: Removing the endpoint and using the normal s3 url (`http://s3-west-1.amazon...`) works as expected, but I want to use my custom dns entry.

Thanks.

Comment: did you figure it out? I'm facing the same thing right now :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using the option `force_path_style: false` to use the subdomain style.

```
AWS::S3.new.buckets["assets.mydomain.com"].objects["image.jpg"]
  .url_for(:get, {:expires => 20.hours.from_now, force_path_style: false }).to_s
```

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#url_for-instance_method

Comment: The default for force_path_style is false. Anyway, I tried with both false and true and nothing changes :(